# using list of index for repeating index of dataframe in every 3 rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have dataframe like picture:

[image]

and I have index list:

```py
index = ["A", "B","C"]
```

I want every 3 rows this index repeat like picture:

[image]

Is there a efficient way to do it?
Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This would be easy if you did it to the data before converting to a DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this trick:

```
df.index = (df.index % 3 + 65).map(chr)
print(df)

# Output
          0
A  0.410769
B  0.588686
C  0.173944
A  0.911229
B  0.424803
C  0.671895
A  0.665640
B  0.071965
C  0.050997
A  0.965870
B  0.119070
C  0.230928
```

In ASCII, 'A' has the value 65, 'B' 66, 'C' 67 and so on...

If you want to use your index, use:

```
# Enhanced by @mozway
df.index = (df.index % len(index)).map(dict(enumerate(index)))
print(df)

# Output
          0
A  0.410769
B  0.588686
C  0.173944
A  0.911229
B  0.424803
C  0.671895
A  0.665640
B  0.071965
C  0.050997
A  0.965870
B  0.119070
C  0.230928
```

With this solution, the length of your index list or the dataframe doesn't matter.

Comment: Simplest answer. To match the requirements, I would suggest to `map(dict(enumerate(index)))` as alternative ;)

Comment: Why I didn't think to `enumerate`... :( And thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the list to the desired length then use `pandas.Dataframe.reindex`:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide a reproducible example of your problem, I have generated a random list and assigned them to the dataframe, but the approach to the solution will be the same.

If you are sure about the number of elements in the first column (12) you can try:

```py
import random
import pandas as pd
values = random.sample(range(6000, 8000), 12) # Random list, you won't need this line

df = pd.DataFrame({"values": values})
alphabets = ["A", "B", "C"] * 4
df["new_column"] = alphabets
df
```

If not, you can follow code below:

```py
import random
import pandas as pd
values = random.sample(range(6000, 8000), 12) # Random list, you won't need this line
df = pd.DataFrame({"values": values})
alphabets = ["A", "B", "C"]
newColumn = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  newColumn.append(alphabets[index%3])
df["new_column"] = newColumn
df
```

In either cases, you will have the following result:

|  | values | new_column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 7384 | A |
| 1 | 7014 | B |
| 2 | 6997 | C |
| 3 | 6266 | A |
| 4 | 6552 | B |
| 5 | 6568 | C |
| 6 | 7907 | A |
| 7 | 6209 | B |
| 8 | 7475 | C |
| 9 | 7817 | A |
| 10 | 6293 | B |
| 11 | 6218 | C |